# Java Real-time debugging (gaming)

Tags: java, debugging

In this video :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BES9EKK4Aw4

Notch (minecraft's creator) is doing what he refers to as 'real-time debugging'. He's actually modifying the code and plays with the game at the same time without recompiling everytime.

Does anyone know what this is called or where I could get more information on how to achieve this? I've been looking around without any success!

Regards,
Erwald

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is called "[hotswapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_swapping#Software)" and is supported by certain JVMs. The Eclipse IDE debugger is capable of hot-swapping your code in the debug (<kbd>F11</kbd>) mode. Eclipse can also auto-build your project once you save a modified file (AND hot-swap when running a debug build). Notch seems to be using exactly this technique.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F is a concise explanation of Eclipse's capabilities

Comment: Now that we are diving into details, this feature was enabled by the [JPDA protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/enhancements.html#hotswap) in Java 1.4.2, it seems.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs! Yeah I'm actually using eclipse soo i sure will try this! Thanks you again!

Answer (score 2):

some IDE s are doing this ie: eclipse, netbeans, intellij idea etc.

however some changes requires recompiling (method addition or deletion etc.)

and what he using is probably eclipse.