# Testing/Changing java sources at runtime

Tags: java, debugging, events, runtime, executable-jar

On that video: [Coding with Notch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BES9EKK4Aw4) we can see how Notch makes changes to Minecraft code and can immediately see the changes in game. I think that is very efficient and I would like to know how he does that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three Things

1. He is using the same workstation, He is just extending his screen.
2. Debug mode in Eclipse with breakpoints in those functions that are
   most likely to be called in every actions in the game.
3. Eclipse emulators to run jar files. Similar to apk emulators

Comment: Well I know he is using the same workstation. How he exactly accomplished that?

Comment: Emulators runs the project without a build. Real Time Integrations are achieved through Software development Kits .J2ME is one such emulators

Comment: Isn't J2ME designed for smartphones and mobile phones?

Comment: Yea, they help us to emulate java midlets apps in java/symbian phones. Similar emulators are available for apps that run on PC as well

Comment: Can you give me an example of such emulator for PC?

Comment: I've just found a better answer to the same question asked on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126472/java-real-time-debugging-gaming. What is weird is that I was looking for similar questions before I asked my question and I did not see it.